# Excel VBA Transposing is Resulting in Multiple Entries

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm trying to transpose data with two rows and 238 columns to a list (two columns and 238 rows) that I can then filter to remove the rows that have cells with no values next to them. I'm pretty novice when it comes to VBA, so it took me a while to get the code to work for the transpose function, but when I finally got the data transposed, each column became two duplicate rows (instead of just one), and when it reaches the last category (last column in original configuration), the duplicates continue for about 300 rows. I'm not sure where I went wrong, but I hope the issue is obvious so someone can give me a quick answer haha

Here is the code that I have:

```
Sub Transpose()

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Training List by Position").Range("A4:B10000").Clear

Dim Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range, Rng As Range
Dim rowIndex As Integer
Set Range1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Training List by Position").Range("A1:IB2")
Set Range2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Training List by Position").Range("A4:B300")
columnIndex = 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Rng In Range1.Columns
    Rng.Copy
    Range2.Offset(columnIndex, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
    columnIndex = columnIndex + Rng.Rows.Count
Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're over-complicating this a bit - why do you need anything more than this?

```
Range("A1:IB2").Copy
Range("A4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
```

Comment: Because I don't know completely what I'm doing and apparently found some very complicated, unnecessary code to try and adapt for my needs XD Thank you so much--this works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

dwirony's answer is the best to solve your problem, but if you want to know why each column is duplicating, it happens because rng.rows.count is adding 2 (two) to columnIndex every loop, since in your original data there are two rows of every column.

also it does fill 300 rows because you're asking excel to fill the entire range of Range2 variable, every iteration it pastes to A4:B300, goes down two rows and repeat